# Birth record in Magdeburg on October 11, 1889

Tags: birth-records, german-language

I have a copy of the birth record that was recorded by the registrar Frostdorf in 1889. Main registrar #2091 but most of the handwritten portion isn't legible.

Is it possible to get a better copy and if so, who would I need to contact?

I can tell you that the document stated that my great, great grandfather lived at Magdeburg, Schrenstraße R. 6 and 7.

Comment: Is it completely illegible, or hard to read? If the latter: you could also post it here and have other people take a look.

Comment: I cannot find a "Schrenstr." for Magdeburg. Where does that information come from? Is it possibly misspelled?

Comment: To increase the chances that someone can help you, please [edit] your question to add an image of the document.

Comment: If [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2ABW.jpg) is the image you're having trouble with, can we [edit] it into the question?

Answer (score 1):

The registrar's name is Trostdorf. This person signed birth certificates in Magdeburg - Standesamt Altstadt, but there is no birth record Nr. 2091 for 11 October 1889. Birth records with Nrs. 2091 are in all years around August.

It would be helpful when you could post a picture of the written part you would like an answer for.

Answer (score 0):

To shoover's comment:
The record you linked is for a girl named Ottilie, so it cannot be the great great grandfather.